# php shell_exec not working on windows

Tags: php

I am on Windows. I have a string as follows

```
Ra6tRR8DIsoll/7O5o6DBfRvlbhdj4mGmivRXYiDHD1JpY1WIMpI5HycXp/IsnUF
```

What I am trying to do is perform a shell_exec from php to my console app . The console app command line is as follows

```
consoleapp decrypt Ra6tRR8DIsoll/7O5o6DBfRvlbhdj4mGmivRXYiDHD1JpY1WIMpI5HycXp/IsnUF
```

However when I try to run shell_exec using the command above I get a null as a result. the command works on the console, though.

Is it because there are special characters in the string ? I was looking at escapeshellarg and wondering if it could help resolve this issue ?

following is my code . I am calling the **doDecreyptWithTime** method.

```
private function doDecryptWithTime($string)
    {
        $command =  "aesencryptdecrypt.exe decrypt ". escapeshellarg(trim($string));
        // dd($command);
        return exec($command);

    }

    private function doDecrypt($string)
    {
        $command =  $this->generateEntireCommand(EncryptionCommands::Decrypt). ' ' .$string;
        return shell_exec($command);
        // return  explode(Config::get('myconfig.DecryptDelimiter'),$output);
    }


    private function generateEntireCommand($command)
    {
        if($command == EncryptionCommands::Encrypt)
            return $this->generatePath(). ' '. EncryptionCommands::Encrypt;
        elseif($command == EncryptionCommands::Decrypt)
            return $this->generatePath(). ' '.EncryptionCommands::Decrypt;
        elseif($command == EncryptionCommands::DecryptWithTime)
            return $this->generatePath(). ' '.EncryptionCommands::DecryptWithTime;
    }

    private function  generatePath()
    {
        $fullEncryptFileName = null;
        $encryptFileName =  Config::get('myconfig.EcryptionFileName');
        if(!is_null(Config::get('myconfig.EcryptionFileName')))
        {
            $fullEncryptFileName = public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.Config::get('myconfig.EncryptFileLocation').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$encryptFileName;
        }
        else
        {
            $fullEncryptFileName = public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->fileLocation.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$encryptFileName;
        }

        if(!is_null($fullEncryptFileName))
            return $fullEncryptFileName;
        else
            throw new Exception('could not generate the filename');
    }
```

**Update 1** :
I am on php 5.5 so i Believe that the safe_mode functionality is not available any more. Also I have checked the disabled functions list, shell_exec, exec are not listed there .
please suggest!

Comment: check if safe_mod is off and shell_exec is not disabled

Comment: I assume you've tried to `var_dump($command)`?

Comment: Yes , I have var_dump($command) . The command that is generated is correct. but the output is not.

Comment: ..and the user that runs the web server has execution rights to the command, right? Are you sure that it's the absolute path, just in case the command isn't in the system paths of the web user?

Comment: I am on windows and i have made sure that the web server has execution rights. i have also added the exe to the path on the webserver . still stumped !